# Combinatorics: example where order matters for |E| but not seems to matter for |S|

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was in a class where the following example problem for a probability question was given. The instructor could not give an explanation when pressed to explain why $|S|$ seemed to be the cardinality of an ordered set but $|E|$ seemed to be cardinality for an unordered set.

> Roll a die 12 times. What is P(each number appears exactly twice)?
>
> $$
> \frac{{12 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2}{6 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}}{6^{12}}
> $$

If $|S|$ is $6^{12}$ , then $S$ must be an ordered set, so $E$ should be ordered as well, but doesn't the "*n choose k*" paradigm do away with ordering (of the chosen elements)? I mean, isn't that the role of the $2!$ in the denominator of the following?

$${12 \choose 2} = \frac{12!}{10!2!}$$

Comment: In writing the question, you never define $S$ and $E$. It appears that $S$ is the set of all ordered series of $12$ elements and $E$ is the set of ordered series that have two of each.  You should not expect your readers to figure this out.  As others have shown, $|S|$ is not correct.

Comment: Sorry. That was an error due to the lateness of the hour. But the question stands, right?

Comment: The "n choose k" ignores the order of the elements in that pair, which is correct.  With the $12 \choose 2$ you are choosing the slots that the first pair goes into without concern for which of the slots each element gets, which is correct.  But you *are* paying attention to the order of the slots relative to the other pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$12!$ is false! How can factorials be possibly related to dice rolls?

In fact, you should have $6^{12}$ in the denominator. This is also an "ordered" realm (which you should deal with every time when you have a question about physical objects like dice and coins): Each $6$ is the number of different rolls of a corresponding die.

But numerator is "ordered" as well. However, is does not count unordered random choices of some objects. Instead, it counts the number of ways in which you can assign rolls to dice: $12 \choose 2$ to assign the ones, $10 \choose 2$ for the twos etc.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain more how the numerator is ordered? My understanding is that "12 choose 2" doesn't distinguish between the two orderings in which the twos could appear in relation to each other.

Comment: @JellicleCat, it does. Say, the fifth roll is two and ninth roll is two. This is, of course, the same as saying that the ninth roll is two and the fifth roll is two. So we take in account the order in which results appear, while, naturally, ignoring the order in which we register the results.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is wrong.

The numerator simplifies to $\dfrac{12!}{2^6}$ which is OK
[permutation with repetitions]

The denominator should be $6^{12}$

Comment: Right. Sorry about the denominator, but 6^12  is ordered, right? So do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: The direct formula for determining the number of distinct ways to permute a multiset of $n$ elements wit $n_1$ of one kind, $n_2$ of another.... is given by the multinomial coefficient ${n\choose n_1, n_2, .....}$ which here would be ${12\choose 2,2,2,2,2,2}$. If you expand ${12\choose 2}{10\choose2}...$ and cancel out common terms, you will see that what you get is the multinomial coefficient. You could also  look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Just in case you think that all $n_k's$ need to be equal, they need not. Any multinomial coefficient can be expressed as the product of binomial coefficients, e.g. ${9\choose 4,3,2} = {9\choose 4}{5\choose 3}{2\choose 2}$